# NullPointerException when starting a Popupwindow with default values set, otherwise it works

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, initialization, popupwindow

When I open a Popup-window by a button event from the maincontroller
the popup appears and everything looks perfect.
But when I try to set data in comboboxes or textfields

PopUpPersController:

```
public PopUpPersController() {
    initialize();
}
private void initialize() {
    txtMa_LohnGesKum.setText("1200.12");
}
```

and press the button to open the popup, I get a null pointer exception.

The `maincontroller` is called `Projektcontroller`, 
the associated `FXML-file` is called `Projekt.fxml`
The popupwindow controller is called "PopUpPersController", 
the associated `FXML-file` called `PersCalc.fxml`.
All elements have fxId's.
I thought the filling of comboboxes or textfields with defaultdata would work the same way as in the Maincontroller...
I did not find an answer that covers this question.

I am quite new to Java, so thanks a lot for your help and best regards
Marcus

The code from the Main or ProjectController for the Button opening the popupwindow:

```
@FXML
void onAction_Test(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        Parent root1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/ui/fxml/PersCalc.fxml"));
        Stage persStage = new Stage();
        persStage.setTitle("Personalkosten-Rechner");
        persStage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
        persStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I tried to identify the major errors:

1. javafx.fxml.LoadException in PersCalc.fxml

The code in this line:

```
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1"xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ui.controller.PopUpPersController">
```

2.From the button event in the ProjectController (see above)
The code in this line:

```
Parent root1=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/ui/fxml/PersCalc.fxml"));
```

3.The assignment of data to the `textfield`

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   ui.controller.PopUpPersController.initialize(PopUpPersController.java:123)

The code in this line (see above `initialize()`):

```
 txtMa_LohnGesKum.setText("1200.12");
```

Comment: [mcve] please ...

Answer (score 2):

Loading a fxml containing the `fx:controller` attribute results in `FXMLLoader` using the constructor taking 0 arguments to create an instance of the controller class. The constructor is invoked before any of the fields are injected resulting in a `NullPointerException`, even if the fields are accessible to `FXMLLoader` and the fxml file contains the proper `fx:id` attributes.

Assuming you did set up the field/`fx:id` properly, making the `initialize` method visible to `FXMLLoader` instead of invoking `initialize` from the constructor should fix the issue:

```
public PopUpPersController() {
}

@FXML // you need this annotation for non-public members to be visible to FXMLLoader
private void initialize() {
    txtMa_LohnGesKum.setText("1200.12");
}
```

Make sure the fields `FXMLLoader` should inject to are also annotated with `@FXML` (or `public`) and required `fx:id` attributes are set in the fxml file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear explanation. Its works and I got a better insight on what is happening Marcus